# CyanogenMod 13 fall down to 2G when data connection is OFF

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm new to Android 6 and I'm coming straight from 4.2. 
As my region is with lower celluar network coverage, I'm experiencing problems with my network coverage. Now, the problem is that my Galaxy Note 3 is loosing 3G signal, because the 2G is more common here and 3G is avail only in the city. I can't select "3G (preffered)", like I was able to do in Android 4.2, then when I turn on the Data Connection, the phone will switch to 3G, when I turn it off, it'll go to 2G. I can't do that on Android 6.0, and the phone is in HSDPA all the time.

Comment: Settings, sim, select your sim settings and preferred network here.

Comment: No, there are 3 options there. 4G (preffered), 3G, 2G. If I set 2G, then it won't go to 3G when data conn is turned on, instead it'll stay on EDGE. Very annoying...

Comment: You could create different profiles  to change from 2G to 3G and switch in quick toggles.

Comment: That's an idea, but apparently Android 6 has less options than 4.2/4.4 in that direction. So it can't do that autonomously?

Comment: Other suggestions? The worst thing is that it won't go to 2G when 3G signal is lost, and I'm 100% sure that there is 2G coverage in that area..

Answer (score 0):

I am using cyanogenmod in my Xiaomi Redmi 1s, I used to do this steps :

- Open dialer, and type `*#*#4636#*#*`.(I think this setting code may vary with each device manufacturer, search appropriate code for your device)
- It will enter into Testing mode.
- Inside that, tap on Phone Information, look for Set preferred network type, and set it as `WCDMA only`.

This Setting will be lost after every reboot.